# For which values of $c$ are the following sets become smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

For which values of $c$ are the following sets become smooth manifolds

1) $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2} \mid x^3+xy+y^3=c \}$

2) $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R^4} \mid x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2=0, x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=c\}$

---

For part 1,

Let $F(x,y)=x^3+xy+y^3$

$$DF=\left( \begin{array}{}3x^2+y &3y^2+x\end{array} \right)$$

rank$(DF)=0 \iff (x,y)=(0,0)$ or $(x,y)=(-{1 \over 3},-{1 \over 3})$

Therefore, $F(0,0)=0$ and $F(-{1 \over 3},-{1 \over 3})={1 \over 27}$ are the only critical value. Hence $F^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth 1-manifold if $c \neq 0$ or $1 \over 27$.

---

For part 2,

Let $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\left( \begin{array}{}x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2 & x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4\end{array} \right)$

$$DF=\left( \begin{array}{}2x_1 & 2x_2 & -2x_3 & -2x_4 \\ 1 & 2&3&4\end{array} \right)$$

Than rank$(DF)\neq 2 \iff (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=n({1 \over 2},1,-{3 \over 2},-2)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$F(n({1 \over 2},1,-{3 \over 2},-2))=(-{n^2 \over 2},-10n)$

Hence, the only critical value is $(0,0)$ and $F^{-1}(0,c)$ is a smooth 2-manifold if $c \neq 0$.

Am I right?

Comment: Didn't carefully check your algebra; 1. looks good, and your conclusion in 2. looks correct, but how do you know $n$ is an integer?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang $(x_i)=({1 \over 2}, 1, -{3 \over 2}, -2)$ will make $DF$ into a rank 1 matrix, and one of the row operation you can add or take away any scalar multiple of another row. So $n \in \mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note that $c$ being a singular value does not imply that $F^{-1}(c)$ is not a smooth manifold.